# Copy a folder and its contents to USB stick in Ubuntu

Tags: python, linux

How would I create a Python script that copies a folder and all of its contents from my Linux laptop to a USB memory stick?

I have tried using `shutil.copytree` and it wouldn't work. I tried using terminal commands and it just copied the folders but not the files.

copytree error:

```
"/usr/lib/python3.4/os.py", line 237, in makedirs mkdir(name, mode) 
FileExistsError: [Errno 17] File exists: '/media/user/JAKE'
```

Comment: use subprocess with linux commands? use -R

Comment: In what way didn’t `shutil.copytree` work?

Comment: ' import shutil
>>> shutil.copyfile('/home/user/Documents/First_Year', '/media/user/JAKE')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    shutil.copyfile('/home/user/Documents/First_Year', '/media/user/JAKE')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/shutil.py", line 107, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/home/user/Documents/First_Year''

Comment: That is my code and the error I got

Sorry it isn't clear, not sure how to format that properly

Comment: you could call `destination = '/media/user/JAKE';` `shutil.rmtree(destination)` before calling `shutil.copytree(source, destination)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import shutil
shutil.copytree(src,dest)
```

**shutil.copytree(src, dst, symlinks=False, ignore=None)**

*Recursively copy an entire directory tree rooted at src. The destination directory, named by dst, must not already exist; it will be created as well as missing parent directorie*s.

This line is why you see the error:

**The destination directory, named by dst, must not already exist**
Or

if using subprocess, you need the `-R` flag:

```
subprocess.check_call( ["cp", "source", "-R" ,"dest"])
```

Comment: >>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.check_call( ["cp", "'/home/user/Documents/First_Year'", "-R" ,"'/media/user/JAKE'"])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    subprocess.check_call( ["cp", "'/home/user/Documents/First_Year'", "-R" ,"'/media/user/JAKE'"])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 557, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cp', "'/home/user/Documents/First_Year'", '-R', "'/media/user/JAKE'"]' returned non-zero exit status 1

Comment: That is what I get with subprocess

Comment: And I get this with shutil

>>> import shutil
>>> shutil.copytree('/home/user/Documents/First_Year','/media/user/JAKE')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    shutil.copytree('/home/user/Documents/First_Year','/media/user/JAKE')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/shutil.py", line 302, in copytree
    os.makedirs(dst)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/os.py", line 237, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
FileExistsError: [Errno 17] File exists: '/media/user/JAKE'

Comment: are you putting quotes around quotes for the subprocess command?

Comment: and the files already exist so that is what is causing the error for copytree

Comment: I see, I think I might just stick to copying and pasting manually then. Thanks for the input anyway

Comment: remove the directories and use copytree, look at my edited answer, the dest must **not** already exist, change `'/media/user/JAKE'` to `'/media/user/JAKE/copied'`